# error con html2pdf y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html2pdf

disculpen pero tengo un gran error con la libreria Html2Pdf y mi conexion con la base de datos mysql.
pues bien cuando intento generar un arreglo con el contenido de una tabla en mi base de datos me  muestra solo el ultimo registro de la tabla, siendo que le paso de forma correcta el id y mi consulta esta correcta, me arroja que hay un error con el cierre de los ciclos, pero si cierro el ciclo en la consulta no me traeria todos los valores.
si alguien tiene alguna idea de como lo podria solventar seria de gran ayuda

```css
<?php 
 
 require 'conexion.php';
 $cod_eq = $_POST['titulos'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tecnico WHERE id_equipo='$cod_eq'";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>vendor</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  h1{
   color: green;
  }

  #cajas{
   width: 100%;

  }

  .caja{
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: #ccc;
   float: left;
  }

  #cabecera img{
   width: 250px;
   height: 80px;
   float: left;
  }
  #cabecera h2{
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['titulo'])): ?>
 <div id="cabecera">
  <img src="images/logo2.png">
  
  
 </div>
 <div id="cabecera">
  <h2> Historial <?=$_POST['titulo']?></h2>

  
 </div>
 <?php endif;?>


 <div id="cajas">
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>Fecha</td>
   <td>Tecnico</td>
   <td>Telefono</td>
   <td>Contometro Ini.</td>
   <td>Contrometro Fin.</td>
   <td>Detalles</td>
   <td>Componentes</td>
  </tr>
  <?php

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
    $fecha  = $row['fecha'];
    $tecnico = $row['tecnico'];
    $telefono = $row['telefono'];
    $inicial = $row['inicial'];
    $final = $row['final'];
    $detalles = $row['detalles'];
    $componentes = $row['componentes'];
   
   }
   ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $fecha; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $tecnico; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $telefono; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $inicial; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $final; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $detalles; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $componentes; ?></td>
  
  </tr>

 </table>
  
 </div>


 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
 
 require 'conexion.php';
 require './vendor/autoload.php';

 $cod_eq = $_GET['cod_eq'];
 $sql = "SELECT e.cod_eq, e.nom_eq, t.id_equipo, t.id, t.fecha, t.tecnico, t.telefono, t.inicial, t.final, t.detalles, t.componentes FROM equipo e, tecnico t WHERE e.cod_eq='$cod_eq' and e.cod_eq=t.id_equipo";
 $respuesta = $mysqli->query($sql);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
    $nom_eq = $row['nom_eq'];
    $fecha  = $row['fecha'];
    $tecnico = $row['tecnico'];
    $telefono = $row['telefono'];
    $inicial = $row['inicial'];
    $final = $row['final'];
    $detalles = $row['detalles'];
    $componentes = $row['componentes'];
 }

 use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

  if (isset($_POST['crear'])) {
  
   ob_start();
   require_once 'historial.php';
   $html = ob_get_clean();

   $html2 = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'es', 'true', 'UTF-8');

   $html2->writeHTML($html);
   $html2->output('prueba.pdf');

  }
 ?>


 <form action="" method="post">
  
  <input type="text" name="titulos" value="<?php echo $cod_eq; ?>" readonly />
  <input type="text" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $nom_eq; ?>" readonly />
  <input type="submit" name="crear" value="Generar PDF" />

 </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estás generando las filas de la tabla fuera del ciclo, solo necesitas mover la llave de cierre del cliclo:

```
    <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
            $fecha  = $row['fecha'];
            $tecnico = $row['tecnico'];
            $telefono = $row['telefono'];
            $inicial = $row['inicial'];
            $final = $row['final'];
            $detalles = $row['detalles'];
            $componentes = $row['componentes'];
        // } Esto no permitía generar bien las filas

     ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fecha; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tecnico; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $telefono; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $inicial; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $final; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detalles; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $componentes; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
        } // Aquí cierras el ciclo y listo
        // Después de esto debes cerrar todas las etiquetas HTML
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Edición:** Si te falta cerrar una etiqueta, entonces vas a obtener el error que mencionas.

Comment: ya lo hice y no me genera el pdf xq me indica que el orden de cierre esta mal.

Comment: Revisa el HTML con el inspector del navegador para ver cuál etiqueta quedó abierta y es la causante del error.